# Terraform modules for log shipping from EKS (non Fargate) to AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-eks, aws-elasticsearch

I am setting up a new AWS Elasticsearch setup for my EKS Cluster (non Fargate). I see many modules and articles that covers Fargate setups. Other than [cloudposse](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elasticsearch) ones, is there any other modules we can use it and templatize mine?

Comment: There is an example in this resource put out by AWS that might help: https://www.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/230_logging/setup_es/